# Three.js: how to create decals to simple world

Tags: function, three.js, decal

I'm a beginner at coding in general. I was trying to create a mini shooting game where you can shoot decals (some sort of colour stain) into any object in the world. To give an illusion of shooting paint into ojects.

I have used [SimonDev's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSTgk7JT668&lc=UgzYzRg57BssyWF4_8d4AaABAg&ab_channel=SimonDev) tutorial but it doesn't work for me.

Here is a link to the [PROJECT](https://codesandbox.io/s/project-testing-dcals-notworking-9q9rn7?file=/src/index.js)

Honestly I have no clue what the problem could be. Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your example that raycaster finds intersections with objects on the scene. Try creating an arrowHelper, giving it a direction and a starting position for the ray. To begin with, you will see visually whether the direction of the ray is correct.